# sql script help needed with joins

Tags: sql, join

How to merge 3 tables data with a common column.

```
create table #t1 (id varchar(3), name_1 varchar(10))
insert into #t1 values (101,'red')
insert into #t1 values (102,'green')
insert into #t1 values (103,'blue')

create table #t2 (id varchar(3), address_1 varchar(10), state_1 varchar(10))
insert into #t2 values (101,'lon','ab')
insert into #t2 values (101,'fin','pq')
insert into #t2 values (102,'san','cd')
insert into #t2 values (102,'new', 'mn')

create table #t3 (id varchar(3), examdt varchar(10), examtime varchar(10), centre_code varchar(10))
insert into #t3 values (101,'2017-01-01','08:05', 'cod')
insert into #t3 values (101,'2018-04-15','07:15','salm')
insert into #t3 values (101,'2015-08-08', '12:25','targ')
insert into #t3 values (102,'2019-03-11','09:45', 'hen')
insert into #t3 values (102,'2020-05-25','17:15','mint')
insert into #t3 values (103,'2015-05-08', '12:45','fish')
```

I tried:

```
select u.id, name_1, address_1, state_1, examdt, examtime, centre_code from 
(
select id from #t1 union
select id from #t2 union
select id from #t3 ) as u left outer join #t1 on #t1.id = u.id
left outer join #t2 on #t2.id = u.id
left outer join #t3 on #t3.id = u.id
```

After running the above script, it is doing a cross join.

I want it should bring 3 rows with all non-common columns.

Comment: The problem is a lack of unique key in tables.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: You say you want 3 rows - what would those rows look like? Specifically, what data from the sample tables would be in each row?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an inner join. I updated the ID values in your inserts as based on the description I think you meant to insert ID 101, 102, and 103 (not all of them as 101).

Updated table create statements:

```
create table #t1 (id varchar(3), name_1 varchar(10))
    insert into #t1 values (101,'red')
    insert into #t1 values (102,'green')
    insert into #t1 values (103,'blue')
    
create table #t2 (id varchar(3), address_1 varchar(10), state_1 varchar(10))
    insert into #t2 values (101,'lon','ab')
    insert into #t2 values (102,'san','cd')
    insert into #t2 values (103,'new', 'mn')

create table #t3 (id varchar(3), examdt varchar(10), examtime varchar(10), centre_code varchar(10))
    insert into #t3 values (101,'2017-01-01','08:05', 'cod')
    insert into #t3 values (102,'2018-05-15','07:15','salm')
    insert into #t3 values (103,'2015-05-08', '12:25','targ')
```

Query to return data from all 3 tables:

```
select u1.id, u1.name_1, u2.address_1, u2.state_1, u3.examdt, u3.examtime, u3.centre_code 
from #t1 u1
join #t2 u2 on (u2.id = u1.id)
join #t3 u3 on (u3.id = u1.id)
```

Output:

```
id |name_1|address_1|state_1|examdt    |examtime|centre_code|
---+------+---------+-------+----------+--------+-----------+
101|red   |lon      |ab     |2017-01-01|08:05   |cod        |
102|green |san      |cd     |2018-05-15|07:15   |salm       |
103|blue  |new      |mn     |2015-05-08|12:25   |targ       |
```

Comment: i updated the test data as i have multiple rows in each table for single id.. that is the problem.. there is no unique id to join all 3 tables.. only id is the key to join them together.

Answer (score 0):

one unique key constraint will solve the issue across three tables.

Comment: there is no unique id to join all 3 tables only id is the column which is common in all 3 tables. as i had multiple rows in table for each row , updated the test data